# Making links stick to a textfield

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Hey guys I'm making a new layout for my community and now I'm slicing him into pieces. Their is only 1 problem I designed a textfield where the user can search but there are 2 links right after the textfield. I don't know how to let them stick together. I've tried something and it actually works in google chrome, but in it doesn't.

```
.searchbox {
    background: url('../images/searchbox.gif') no-repeat;
    border: 0px; 
    height: 24px;
    width: 308px;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 1px -15px 0px 10px;
}
.options {
    background: url('../images/options_active.gif') repeat-x;
    background: url('../images/options.gif') repeat-x;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
    color: #6b6b6b;
}
.options:active {
    background: url('../images/options_active.gif') repeat-x;
    color: #000;
}
.button {
    background: url('../images/button_bg_active.gif') repeat-x;
    background: url('../images/button_bg.gif') repeat-x;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
}
.button:active {
    background: url('../images/button_bg_active.gif') repeat-x;
}
```

this is what I've got in my css file

this is my html file:

```
<div id="topbar">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" class="searchbox" name="searchbox" value="Zoek events, nieuws, dj's, foto's en veel meer..." />
        <a href="#showOptions" class="options" title="Advanced options">Advanced options</a>
        <a href="#submitform" class="button" title="Zoeken!">Zoeken!</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks in firefox:
[alt text http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/8282/searchj.png](http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/8282/searchj.png)

and this is what it looks in chrome:
[alt text http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/2655/searchchrome.png](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/2655/searchchrome.png)

Comment: Padding value cannot be negative.

Comment: please define "stick together" more

Comment: well the buttons their borders need to be together, with no white space between it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with you might also want to use `-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px` and `-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px` to get that same effect with Chrome and Safari.

I would do something like the following:

```
.form {
    position: relative; /* Alows you to absolutely position child elements */
}

.searchbox {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
.options, .button {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
}
.options {
    right: -30px; /* Width of the button to its right */
}
```